# How to implement multiple associations between models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have 4 models.

1. `UserModel`
2. `SkillModel`
3. `UserSkillModel`
4. `PreferenceSkillModel`

Association I used:

```
UserModel
has_many :skills, through: :user_skills
has_many :user_skills
has_many :skills, :through: :preference_skills
has_many :preference_skills

SkillModel
has_many :users, through: :user_skills
has_many :users_skills
has_many :users, :through: :preference_skills
has_many :preference_skills

UserSkillModel
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :skill

PreferenceSkillModel
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :skill
```

Schema:

```
create_table "preference_skills", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id", default: 0
    t.integer "skill_id", default: 0
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

 create_table "user_skills", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "skill_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "skills", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", default: ""
    t.integer "skill_count", default: 0
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

How can I implement this association in a correct way?

Comment: What's the difference between `user_skills` & `preference_skills`?

Comment: user_skills are those skills which I choose as my skills. but preference_skills are those skills which I looking for in other people. like my settings.

Comment: what's the schema for all `Skill` models?

Comment: I add schema in question please check.

Comment: Define "correct way"? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: i get this error when i try to do any operation: Cannot have a has_many :through association 'User#skills' which goes through 'User#preference_skills' before the through association is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I implement this association in a correct way?

What is correct may depend on what you are trying to do.  The following is correct, by naming separate associations for users-skills and users-preference_skills.

```
class User
  has_many :user_skills
  has_many :my_skills, through: :user_skills, class_name: 'Skill'
  has_many :preference_skills
  has_many :my_preference_skills, :through: :preference_skills, class_name: 'Skill'
  ...
end

class SkillModel
  has_many :users_skills
  has_many :direct_users, through: :user_skills, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :preference_skills
  has_many :preference_users, :through: :preference_skills, class_name: 'User'
  ...
end
```

If you want one collection with all the skills you need to use STI or polymorphism.  Read the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a need for separate `user_skills` & `preference_skills` models.
You can use `STI` here like -

`skill.rb`
    Skill < ApplicationRecord
    end

`user_skill.rb`

```
UserSkill < Skill
end
```

`preference_skill.rb`

```
PreferenceSkill < Skill
end
```

> Note: The `Skill` model that I've used is different from what you are assuming.
>   You might want to rename your current `Skills` model to more explainatory name like `SkillDetail`.

After this you can have your associations like -

```
class User < AR
  has_many :skills
  has_many :skill_details, through: :skills
end

class Skill < AR
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :skill_detail
end

class SkillDetail < AR
  has_many :skills
  has_many :users, through: :skills
end
```

> P.S. Do some research on `Single Table Inheritance (STI)`

Hope this helps.
Also note that you got a downvote because this is a very vague question & you are directly asking to implement a business logic.